# add custom attribute or metadata to file java

Tags: java, file, io, metadata

I have files that need an extra attribute called "encryption used". But this gives "IllegalArgumentExeption". I know why it gives that error, "encryption used" isn't known as an attribute, but is there a way I can force it to be? Or add custom metadata to the file?

```
 Path path = new File("/propertyfiles/encdec.properties").toPath();

    try{
        Files.setAttribute(path, "encryption used", "testtesttest");
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try{
        System.out.println(Files.getAttribute(path, "encryption used"));
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: does this attribute mean that file `encdec.properties` is encryped?

Comment: It means whatever you want it to mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your file system supports user-defined (aka extended) attributes, then the way to set one would be like this:

```
Files.setAttribute(path, "user:encryption used", "testtesttest");
```

As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) for `setAttribute` explains, the 2nd argument takes the form of an optional *view-name* and an attribute name.  In this case, you need to use the [`UserDefinedFileAttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html) whose view-name is "user".

Note that different file system types support different attribute views, and your file system *may not* support this one.  This particularly applies across different operating systems; e.g. you can't read a file's MacOS file attributes on a Linux system via these APIs.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that extended attributes are platform dependent, so an attribute on a file created, let's say, on MacOS, cannot be read on Linux (at least not naturally)